# Call event after variable has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, spotify

For a school project I'm working on making a website that makes users listen along with each other.

So far I have this button which will let the user listen to the song which another user is listening right now including the right position. But this will only call this function once.

What I want is when [randomNummer} changes it will call that function again automatically. Does anyone know how I can do this and what I have to use to achieve this?

This is the code for the button:

```
         document.getElementById('play-song').addEventListener('click', function() {      
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play',
          type: 'PUT',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
          },
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify({
            "uris": [randomNummer],
            "position_ms": seconds
          })
        });
        }, false);
```

randomNummer is currently generated with an Array:

```
var randomNummer;      
    var myArray = [
      "spotify:track:1EtcyegB7JLkAwwqiPyeJ6", 
      "spotify:track:6rAXHPd18PZ6W8m9EectzH", 
      "spotify:track:5qaEfEh1AtSdrdrByCP7qR", 
      "spotify:track:1CnPYaKxTVb4LWOtiGOm0m", 
      "spotify:track:3qEg6xYffvuvwpq4U6FRrK"
    ];

    setInterval(function(){
           callItem();
        }, 200000); 
   var callItem = function(){       
    randomNummer = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
      document.getElementById("song-uri").innerHTML = randomNummer;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you used Jquery. So...
First of all a bit change your code:

```
$('#play-song').on('click', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play',
    type: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      "uris": $("#song-uri").val(),
      "position_ms": seconds
    })
  });
}, false);
```

And:

```
var randomNummer;
var myArray = [
  "spotify:track:1EtcyegB7JLkAwwqiPyeJ6",
  "spotify:track:6rAXHPd18PZ6W8m9EectzH", 
  "spotify:track:5qaEfEh1AtSdrdrByCP7qR", 
  "spotify:track:1CnPYaKxTVb4LWOtiGOm0m", 
  "spotify:track:3qEg6xYffvuvwpq4U6FRrK"
];
setInterval(function(){
  callItem();
}, 200000);
var callItem = function(){
  randomNummer = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  $("#song-uri").val(randomNummer);
}
```

In this case we will use hidden input for storing random number:

```
<input type="hidden" id="song-uri" />
```

And finally catch change event:

```
$("#song-uri").on('change', function(e){
  //event on change random value
});
```

Comment: When I implement this I get ''Undefined'' as randomNummer in my console

Comment: It seems to be working for the majority now. Only that catch change event doesn't seem to be doing anything. I've tested it like this: `            $("#song-uri").on('change', function(e){
            buttonPressed = +1;
            });` but no changes at all to the value of buttonPressed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var randomNummer = {
    value: function value(newValue) {
        // if a new value is set, assign it to the internal "_value" and trigger the callback which can do stuff as you want
        if (typeof newValue !== "undefined") {
            this._value = newValue;
            this.callback();
        }
        // always return the current value
        return this._value;
    },
    callback: function callback() {
        // do the stuff you want to do after value alters
        console.log("Value altered to " + this._value);
    }    
};

var myArray = [
      "spotify:track:1EtcyegB7JLkAwwqiPyeJ6", 
      "spotify:track:6rAXHPd18PZ6W8m9EectzH", 
      "spotify:track:5qaEfEh1AtSdrdrByCP7qR", 
      "spotify:track:1CnPYaKxTVb4LWOtiGOm0m", 
      "spotify:track:3qEg6xYffvuvwpq4U6FRrK"
];

var callItem = function() {
    document.getElementById("song-uri").innerHTML = randomNummer.value(myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)]);
}
setInterval(callItem, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="song-uri"></div>
```

Variables are kind of dumb. But you can give them a little control if you don’t assign new values directly, but with a function.